# is there a reason not to use align?

Tags: equations, align

I have plenty of equations, some of them single lined and some of them with multiple lines which I normaly using the `align` environment. Now my question is:

- Is there a reason to use `equation` over `align` for single line equations?

I will focus on `pdftext` for the case that it would matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out and notice the vertical spacing

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
short
\begin{equation}
  a=b
\end{equation}
this is a very long text with no purpose
\begin{equation}
  a=b
\end{equation}
short
\begin{align}
  a=b
\end{align}
this is a very long text with no purpose
\begin{align}
  a=b
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

`equation` has the trick that it can look at the text before and act accordingly (not adding vertical space if the time is right). `align` has no such feature.

BTW: WHat do you mean by `pdftext`?

[image]

Comment: Ah okey. Thank you for the explenation. Well I meant pdftext rather than pure old latex. Since I'm not very familiar with all the underlying stuff going on (especially ps-tricks) I thought it might be better to include the extra info.

Comment: Well there is no ps-tricks in the standard math setup.